# Apache rewrite issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following lines in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^/?movielist/([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)\.html$ modules.php?module=movies&do=main&pg=$1&ipp=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?movielist/(genre|year|stars)/([a-zA-Z0-0%20]+)$ modules.php?module=movies&do=main&sort=$1&$1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?movielist/(genre|year|stars)/([a-zA-Z0-0%20]+)/([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)\.html$ modules.php?pg=1&ipp=20&module=movies&do=main&sort=$1&$1=$2 [L]
```

If i point the url, for example, to /movielist/Drama, the script works. The issue is with the pagination. If i point to /movielist/Drama/1-20.html i get  404 error. Any ideas why ?

If i point to the un-rewritten URL, it works.

Comment: Based on the rules I'm reading (I could be misreading them), `/movielist/drama` shouldn't work, but `movielist/genere/drama` should. Is what you've pasted exactly what's in your .htaccess?

Comment: You have no rule that matches `Drama` following `movielist/`.  You either expect a numeric value in the first rule, or `genre|year|starts` in the other rules.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.... `/movielist/genre/Drama works`, not `/movielist/Drama`, still issue with 1-20, which is the pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule has some issues. The target of the last rule (the one that matches against pagination) isn't uses any of those numbers:

```
modules.php?pg=1&ipp=20&module=movies&do=main&sort=$1&$1=$2 [L]
```

So the `$3` and `$4` backreferences are never used, is it supposed to be:

```
modules.php?pg=$3&ipp=$4&module=movies&do=main&sort=$1&$1=$2 [L]
```

Other than that, I don't get a 404 when I put those rules in a blank htaccess in a vanilla apache install. `/movielist/genre/Drama/1-12.html` gets rewritten to `/modules.php?pg=1&ipp=20&module=movies&do=main&sort=genre&genre=Drama`, except that the `1` and `12` never get used.

Comment: Thanks for ponting that out! This made me uncover some coding issues. I fixed them and the following code works now: `RewriteRule ^/?movielist/([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)\.html$ modules.php?module=movies&do=main&pg=$1&ipp=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?movielist/(genre|year|stars)/([a-zA-Z0-0%20\-]+)$ modules.php?module=movies&do=main&sort=$1&$1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?movielist/(genre|year|stars)/([a-zA-Z0-0%20\-]+)/([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)\.html$ modules.php?pg=$3&ipp=$4&module=movies&do=main&sort=$1&$1=$2 [L]`